# Empty sheet when using TEXT_CONVERT_XLS_TO_SAP FM

Tags: abap

The Function Module 'TEXT_CONVERT_XLS_TO_SAP' opens a new empty excel sheet while uploading the file.
Please give me a solution for this. I do not want the empty excel file to be opened.

Comment: What worked for me is to close the Excel file to be uploaded before running the program - or use other means like CL_GUI_FRONTEND_SERVICES=>GUI_UPLOAD

Comment: can you please show your source code

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use the FM **ALSM_EXCEL_TO_INTERNAL_TABLE** for Excel-Sheet to internal table conversion. Try it out, it's much easier.